# Server hanging on wrong url cal?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When I have my application on tomcat or weblogic and having the following controller:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/loadByReceiptNo/{receiptNo}/{cashId}")
public Securities loadByReceiptNo(@PathVariable int receiptNo,  @PathVariable int cashId) {

  return myService.loadByReceiptNo(receiptNo, cashId);
}
```

calling

```
/loadByReceiptNo/1
```

or

```
/loadByReceiptNo/1/
```

cause the server hanging for too long and it needs a restart.
how should I avoid such a situation?

> UPDATE

this url is being called by another machine and this url serves as webservice. Getting dump threat, I realized that this part of client stuck in deadlock:

```
conn.getResponseCode()
```

The temporal relief to this issue is using:

```
conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
```

Any other solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: Try taking thread dump and see where its stucked.

Comment: Try webservice from same machine where server is hosted. Is your server or client behind firewall ? You may want to start with `ping` of servers IP address from client machine.

Comment: We are at developing stage, since that the client and server are both on a same machine. No firewalls included.

Comment: It's not really stuck in a deadlock, is it? That would be a serious bug.

Comment: Yeah it does, very surprising for me either.

Answer (score 0):

You are providing wrong URL - `/loadByReceiptNo/1`. You should also provide {cashId} and not just {receiptNo}. So your URL should be something like `/loadByReceiptNo/1/1`.

Reason being @Pathvariable **cannot be null**. You would probably want to do something like -

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value={"/loadByReceiptNo/{receiptNo}/{cashId}","/loadByReceiptNo/{receiptNo}"})
public Securities loadByReceiptNo(@PathVariable Map<String, String> pathVariablesMap) {
    if (pathVariables.containsKey("receiptNo") && pathVariables.containsKey("cashId")) {
       myService.loadByReceiptNo(receiptNo, cashId);
    } else {
        //probably return error response
    }

}
```

or write a new controller method altogether for just `/loadByReceiptNo/{receiptNo}`.

OR you can make cashId as `@RequestParam(value="cashId ",required=false)` and make it optional.

Either ways your current Mapping is incorrect. However these thing should not let you server hang. So either there is a deadlock or your service/dao call is taking too long. If that is the case I suggest use asynchronous processing like using `activemq` and not hold server threads. Just return after validation with error or success code and then process the request from the queue.